# Catching drag-and-drop within a textarea

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-events

I'm trying to catch the events that tell me when a change occurs to a textarea. The jQuery event 'keyup' is mostly fine. What I can't figure out is the event that happens when I highlight some text within the textarea and then drag-and-drop it elsewhere in the same textarea. What event is that?

It feels I got close with this bit modified from a similar question. It catches the event but doesn't actually do the drop for me:

```
$("textarea")
.bind("dragover", false)
.bind("dragenter", false)
.bind("drop", function(e) {
    $("span").append("dropped!");
    return true;
});
```

Play with that here: http://jsfiddle.net/eflat/gbEsq/ -- don't know if that's the right path to go down or not...

Answer (score 0):

I always thought that the `input` event caught all user modifications to a `<textarea>`.

Comment: You mean the 'oninput' event? That looks to be an HTML5 thing and we're not there yet.